# Компилятор ошибочно принимает текст за строки кода

Tags: c++, строки

Надо присвоить переменной значение, которое состоит по факту из строк "машинного" кода, компилятор ошибочно принимает некоторые элементы текста за код и сыпется ошибками, как это обойти?

Присвоить нужно такой кусок текста:

```
DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 2, "ACDT", "CpuPlug", 0x00003000)
{
    External (_SB_.CPU0, ProcessorObj)

    Method (PMPM, 4, NotSerialized) {
       If (LEqual (Arg2, Zero)) {
           Return (Buffer (One) { 0x03 })
       }

       Return (Package (0x02)
       {
           "plugin-type", 
           One
       })
    }

    If (CondRefOf (\_SB.CPU0)) {
        If ((ObjectType (\_SB.CPU0) == 0x0C)) {
            Scope (\_SB.CPU0) {
                If (_OSI ("Darwin")) {
                    Method (_DSM, 4, NotSerialized)  
                    {
                        Return (PMPM (Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Естественно там где стоят "" или бэкслэши ему виднеется код и он пытается его скомпилировать в том числе, а я хочу в строку этот текст внести, не важно string, wstring

Comment: Ничего не понятно... где тут C++?

Comment: C++ тут нету, мне нужно переменной присвоить значение, которое я обозначил как "код"

Comment: Вы только затуманили суть вопроса своим кодом, который к сути вопроса не имеет никакого отношения... :(

Comment: Не отрицаю, что я неправильно оформил вопрос, но я хотел выделить что вот такой специфичный кусок текста надо присвоить переменной, так что прошу прощения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вам нужен сырой литерал `R"(...)"`:

```
::std::string text
{
R"(DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 2, "ACDT", "CpuPlug", 0x00003000)
{
    External (_SB_.CPU0, ProcessorObj)

    Method (PMPM, 4, NotSerialized) {
       If (LEqual (Arg2, Zero)) {
           Return (Buffer (One) { 0x03 })
       }

       Return (Package (0x02)
       {
           "plugin-type", 
           One
       })
    }

    If (CondRefOf (\_SB.CPU0)) {
        If ((ObjectType (\_SB.CPU0) == 0x0C)) {
            Scope (\_SB.CPU0) {
                If (_OSI ("Darwin")) {
                    Method (_DSM, 4, NotSerialized)  
                    {
                        Return (PMPM (Arg0, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})"
};
```

Comment: Благодарю, абсолютно то, что нужно!